# Running simple QtWebEngine app on Raspberry Pi 2, page not showing

Tags: qt5, raspberry-pi2, yocto, qtwebengine

I compiled and installed **QtWebEngine** + QML plugins on Raspberry Pi 2 with Yocto recipes using information in this [tutorial using Yocto `dizzy` branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422646/how-to-install-run-qml-qtwebengine-qtwebkit-on-sbc-using-yocto-unable-to-f) and run the following script:

```
root@raspberrypi2:~# more chromium.qml 
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtWebEngine 0.9
ApplicationWindow {
    width: 1280
    height: 720
    color: "lightgray"
    visible: true
    WebEngineView {
        id: webview
        url: "file:///home/root/hello.html"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

Note that the IMPORT VERSION 0.9, not 1.0

I have tried both `url: "file:///home/root/hello.html"` and `url: "https://duckduckgo.com"` but all I am getting is a red screen with the black square mouse pointer.

```
root@raspberrypi2:~# more hello.html 
<html>
<header><title>This is title</title></header>
<body>
Hello world
</body>
</html>
```

[image: raspberry pi 2 LCD showing first white then red canvas with mouse pointer]

On the console:

```
root@raspberrypi2:~# /usr/bin/qt5/qmlscene -v -platform eglfs chromium.qml 
[0605/163256:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(280)] locale_file_path.empty()
[0605/163257:WARNING:proxy_service.cc(890)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
[0605/163257:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(280)] locale_file_path.empty()
```

`PAC support disabled ...` seems to be a none issue [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557708/pac-support-disabled-because-there-is-no-system-implementation)

## UPDATE

I have followed [this step-by-step tutorial (Poky `fido` branch)](http://www.embarcados.com.br/raspberry-pi-2-qt5-yocto-parte-1/) and then added `qtwebengine` (`import QtWebEngine 1.0` this time) and `qtwebengine-qmlplugins` in my Yocto Image and created again my image with `bitbake`

When I booted and ran `/usr/bin/qt5/qmlscene -v -platform eglfs chromium.qml` I could see my HTML page.

I have tested a couple of dozen of websites and not all page show. So their might be a little more to it.

e.g.

```
http://wikipedia.com shows!!! 
http://google.com doesn't show ???
http://https://stackoverflow.com/ shows!!!
http://facebook.com doesn't
```

Any further pointers are welcome

## UPDATE 20160309

```
root@raspberrypi2:~/app# uname -a
Linux raspberrypi2 4.1.10 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Feb 17 16:51:44 CET 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux


root@raspberrypi2:~/app# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-4.1-noarch:core-4.1-arm
Distributor ID: poky
Description:    Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro) 2.0.1
Release:    2.0.1
Codename:   jethro
```

#### QML

```
root@raspberrypi2:~/app# more chromium.qml 
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtWebEngine 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 800
    height: 600
    color: "lightgray"
    visible: true
    WebEngineView {
        id: webview
        //url: "http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/" // PASS
        //url: "http://google.com" // FAIL
        //url: "http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" // PASS but no Sound
        //url: "https://youtube.com/" // FAIL
        //url: "https://opentokrtc.com/anybots" // FAIL
        //url: "http://speedof.me/" // PASS
        url: "http://facebook.com"  // FAIL
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

Comment: I has the same problem on windows machine. After video driver installation this  problem resolved.

Comment: Interesting. so you really had some URLs that were showing properly right? but others not. Can you be more specific of what you did, that may be a good hint to figure out what's happening on my side. Cheers!

Comment: I didn't has QWebView, I has just a Qt Quick app. But after application start only a white screen was. Installation last driver fixed a problem.

Comment: Ok then it was a different issue. Hey thanks anyway!

Comment: If on raspberry pi exist X Server, you can try to use QWebView from Qt Widgets or recompile qt without OpenGL support. If this will work fine, the problem in video driver. This is a very common mistake with OpenGL on Qt.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it is a little late but I tried to build QtWebEngine in Qt 5.6 alpha and it works properly for me on Raspberry Pi 2 for all the URLs you listed. This is a [demo](https://bugfreeblog.duckdns.org/2015/12/hardware-acceleration-on-webkit-1.html). Maybe they fixed something in QtWebEngine, so you can try 5.6-alpha.

Comment: Luca on which OS are you running Qt? I have updated my question with the details of my environment See UPDATE 20160309.

Comment: Raspbian and raspbian lite.

Comment: Actually even better, how do you install Qt5.6 + QtWebEngine on Raspbian? Want to try your setup on the RPi3

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know about raspbian repos. I use my own builds. I uploaded a build here: http://thebugfreeblog.blogspot.it/2016/03/binaries-for-hardware-accelerated-qt.html. Or you can download a complete firmware here: http://thebugfreeblog.blogspot.it/2016/03/fully-optimised-raspbian-jessie-lite.html.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the branch jethro for meta-qt5 the qtwebengine caused many problems.

I was happy to see that in this branch master with chromium 45:

Branch jethro:
QT_MODULE BRANCH CHROMIUM = "40.0.2214-based"

Branch master:
QT_MODULE BRANCH CHROMIUM = "45-based"

I will try to build;)

Comment: Dİd you try to build master branch? I am dealing with same problem on jethro branch.